# Angular date comparison keep return wrong result

Tags: angular, typescript, date

I was having some problem when trying to compare dates in Angular typescript. Here is my code:

```
let todayDate = new Date();
if ((Date.parse(this.staff.staffDOB.format(DATE_FORMAT))) >= (Date.parse(this.datePipe.transform(todayDate, DATE_FORMAT)))){
            this.isValidDob = false;
        }
```

The example of staffDOB is in this format `'2019-03-07'`. Then I kept getting `true` returned regardless of changing the compare operator to `<=` or `>=`.

I not sure which part went wrong. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @TheParam Mine is not JavaScript though, it is typescript

Comment: TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, so the runtime behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Date#getTime() first.

Comment: Can you try doing `new Date(DATE_FORMAT).getTime() >= new Date(todayDate).getTime()` ?

Comment: What is the result of this.datePipe.transform(todayDate, DATE_FORMAT)

Comment: @AskYous I am trying to compare the specified date with today date though

Comment: Ok. You can get todays date with `new Date().getTime()`. Just don't pass any parameters.

Comment: I think I wrote my code wrong. Try this: `new Date(this.staff.staffDOB).getTime() >= new Date().getTime()`.

Comment: @AskYous I am getting this error message: Argument of type Moment is not assignable to type of string

Comment: Ok. That means your using MomentJS. So you can do `this.staff.staffDob.isSameOrAfter(new Date())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using Moment.js. So you can do:

```
this.staff.staffDob.isSameOrAfter(new Date())
```

More details: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/